# Use of initial "at" followed by the username

Tags: support, comment-replies

Say a user is called Beowulf.  In a comment under his posting you try to start with "@Beowulf".  I know I've seen this done.  But several times, the software has edited that out when I hit "save".  I have no idea how to tell when this will happen and when it won't.  That the software can overrule my decisions about content seems bizarre, not to mention abusive.  What's going on?

Comment: My understanding is that it will edit out superfluous "@user" instances. For example, if it is a comment on Beowulf's post, Beowulf would get notified anyway, so the software edits it out.

Comment: @Jim is right. Relevant post on meta.stackoverflow.com: [Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation)

Comment: A related question: [Are users here not dear?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2513/are-users-here-not-dear). Hendrik Vogt's [answer here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/ping-only-works-for-the-first/2078#2078) gives further explanations and a link to the documentation of the notification system.

Comment: Here's a further thread in which this automatic removal was discussed: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/comment-error-while-posting-comments

Comment: See also [Why does @someone sometimes disappear from comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6281/why-does-someone-sometimes-disappear-from-comments) and the posts [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/6281).

Answer (score 7):

If you click the "help" link under the Add Comment button, it explains that the post owner is *always* notified, making `@postowner` redundant, particularly in the case where your comment is the first one.

> **The post author will always be notified of your comment.** To also notify a *previous*  commenter, mention their user name: @peter or @PeterSmith will both work. Learn more…

Additionally, if you click the "learn more..." link in the abbreviated help it links to the complete help:

https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

There is also autocompletion in the case where multiple people are in the comments, so if you type `@` and don't get a popup for completion, you know that the `@username` is superfluous in that situation.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to type something other than "@" if you really want to include the user's name. Options include "To user" and "!user".

Comment: Or, a construction like, in this case... "Hey @Carl...", or "Dear @Carl, ..."